# GOOGLE Photos API: Getting io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception on listAlbums

Tags: google-photos-api

Straight-up java code, running jdk 10.  On Linux Mint 18.

Have connected to GoogleApis for google drive no problems.
Did all the google setup for GooglePhotos that I did for GoogleDrives

Now trying to do a simple photosClient.listAlbums() and getting exception:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedNoRouteToHostException: null: photoslibrary.googleapis.com/2404....
```

in my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.24.1'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.24.1'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.24.1'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.24.1'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev110-1.23.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with JDK compatibility issues.  When we use Java 7 jdk, things work fine.   When we switch to Java 10, that's when the code breaks.  We have to be on Java 10 for containerization.